# trying to use justify content to move flex box to the right but nothing is happening

Tags: html, css

I am trying to move my items to the right but it is not working

as like `justify-content` won't do anything it won't even center it

I have tried google but can't find the answer,

as I need it to be in line and on the right

```css
.header-container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 30px solid black;
}

.link-container {
  display: flex;
  flex: none;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="header-container">
      <div class="log-container">
      </div>
      <div class="link-container">
        <div class="link-one">
          header link one
        </div>
        <div class="link-two">
          header link two
        </div>
        <div class="link-three">
          header link three
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add `justify-content: flex-end;` to class `header-container`

Answer (score 0):

There is some `CSS` in the `.header-container`  which is not required,

```css
.header-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 30px solid black;
}

.link-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="header-container">
      <div class="log-container">
      </div>
      <div class="link-container">
        <div class="link-one">
          header link one
        </div>
        <div class="link-two">
          header link two
        </div>
        <div class="link-three">
          header link three
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```